# Unable to Set and Unset Cookies in Firefox

Tags: cookies, set, unset

i am unable to set and unset cookies by my simple php script, it works on chrome and internet explorer but not in Firefox

```
unset($_COOKIE['userchatnumber']);
$remembering_timespan = time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$uniuqenumber = mt_rand(200000, 999999);
$uniuqenumber1 = confirm_code($uniuqenumber);
setcookie("userchatnumber", $uniuqenumber1, $remembering_timespan, '/');
$_COOKIE["userchatnumber"] = $uniuqenumber1;
```

it sets but i am unable to set new cookie with same name and also cannot unset cookies

Comment: I solved it myself i was setting cookie on whole site path but my actual directory was one level down and firefox is strict about the cookie path it just works on the path it is configured. i resolved by putting the whole project folder at the root path and setting cookie with whole slash path for whole site and it gets working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself i was setting cookie on whole site path but my actual directory was one level down and Firefox is strict about the cookie path it just works on the path it is configured. i resolved by putting the whole project folder at the root path and setting cookie with whole slash path for whole site and it gets working.